# MERN Stack - Sending file to server using Axios

Tags: node.js, express, axios, multer, mern

I have looked at a number of posts on stack overflow, but nothing I have found has helped me so far. I am trying to send an image (file) from my client side to my server, using MERN stack. I am trying to parse the image with Multer and am using AXIOS to send data to my server side.

Using Postman this works fine, however if I try to send the data via my react frontend it doesn't work.

I want to know why I don't receive the image on the server side when it is sent from my client side

**Client side code**

```
this.onChangeName = this.onChangeName.bind(this);
this.onChangeRetreatImage = this.onChangeRetreatImage.bind(this);
this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

this.state= {
      name : "",
      retreatImage : null
}

onChangeName(event){
 this.setState({
  name : event.target.value
 })
}

onChangeRetreatImage(event){
 this.setState({
  retreatImage : event.target.files[0]
 })
}

onSubmit(event){
 event.preventDefault();

 console.log("Submit form : ", this.state)

 const newRetreat = {
  name : this.state.name,
  retreatImage : this.state.retreatImage
 }

 axios.post('http://localhost:1234/retreats/addRetreat', newRetreat)
  .then(res => console.log(res.data));
}
```

**JSX**

```
<form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} encType="multipart/form-data">

 <div className="form-group">
  <label>Retreat Name</label>
  <input 
    type="text" 
    value={this.state.name} 
    onChange={this.onChangeName}>
  </input>
 </div>

 <div className="form-group">
  <label>Upload Images:</label>
  <input 
   type="file" 
   name="retreatImg1" 
   onChange={this.onChangeRetreatImage}
  </input>
 </div>

 <div className="form-group">
  <input type="submit" value="Create retreat" className="btn btn-primary"></input>
 </div>
</form>
)}
```

When I submit the form I see that this.state.retreatImage is populated:
[image of screenshot of form submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0kP1.png)

However on my server side I have req.file `undefined` and req.body as `{ name : foo, retreatImage : {} }`

So I'm guessing either the form data isn't being sent correctly by my React front end, or multer isn't parsing it correctly when it's sent with AXIOS, as mentioned everything works as expected when using postman.

**Routing**

````
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './uploads/');
  },
  filename: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname + new Date().toISOString());
  }
});

const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits: {
    fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5
  }
});

router.post('/addRetreat', upload.single('retreatImg1'), retreatController.addRetreat);```
````

(I log req.file and req.body in my retreatController)

**Retreat Model**

```
const retreatSchema = new Schema({
  name : { type : String },
  retreatImage : { data : Buffer }
});
```

Thanks in advance for any help given.

I am new to posting question to stack overflow so if there is anything I can do to be clearer please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer, I needed to send the data as FormData and update the headers accordingly

```
onSubmit(event){
//prevent default form logic
event.preventDefault();

const formData = new FormData()
formData.append('name', this.state.name);

//sending multiple images so had to loop through
for(var j = 0; j < this.state.retreatImages.length; j++){
  formData.append(
    'retreatImages',
    this.state.retreatImages[j],
    this.state.retreatImages[j].name
  )
}

console.log("Submit form : ", this.state)

// set headers to pass as final argument in axios post
const headers = {
  Authorization : "Bearer " + token,
  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
}

axios.post('http://localhost:1234/retreats/addRetreat', formData, {
  headers : headers
})
  .then(res => console.log(res.data));
```